# Radius Line Appears on Moving Arc

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I was trying to create these shapes moving, the shape is made up of a semicircle and a symmetric upper arc & lower arc.
They should be just the shape in front but now there are line like a tail dragging behind when they move.
[The output shape with unknown tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpGtr.png)

It seems like these lines are from the moveTo part of upper and lower arcs, but I can't figure out how to solve it.
Where should I change to get rid of it?

```
function Fish(x, y, dx, dy, radius){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.radius = 30;
    
    this.draw = function(){

        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x/0.6, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5, false)
        
        //Upper Arc
        c.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        c.arc(this.x/0.6, this.y+(3*this.radius), this.radius*4, Math.PI * 229/180, Math.PI * 1.5, false)
        
        //Lower Arc
        c.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        c.arc(this.x/0.6, this.y-(3*this.radius), this.radius*4, Math.PI * 131/180 , Math.PI * 0.5, true)
        c.strokeStyle = "green";
        c.stroke();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `arc` method internally traces a `lineTo` from the current pointer's position to the beginning of the arc (defined by cx, cy **and** startAngle).

To workaround that, you need to `moveTo` that position.

Here is a simpler demonstration using a demi-circle with the `startAngle` set at 0 rad:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
document.body.append( canvas );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

const cx = 50;
const cy = 50;
const rad = 30;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo( cx, cy );
ctx.arc( cx, cy, rad, 0, Math.PI );
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.translate( 80, 0 );
const first_point_x = cx + rad; // startAngle is 0
                                // so we just have to add 'rad'
                                // to find the x coord
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo( first_point_x, cy );
ctx.arc( cx, cy, rad, 0, Math.PI );
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();
```

So you would have to calculate the coordinates of the point where your arc will start and `moveTo` that point.
This is doable, but I'm not the best with trigo and your values are quite complex, so instead, here is a workaround using Path2D objects.
If the `arc` command is the first of the sub-path, it will directly `moveTo` that initial point (since there isn't a "current pointer's position" yet).
So we can initialize all our arcs as standalone Path2D objects, made only of these `arc` commands. Then we just have to merge these Path2D objects into a last one and draw that:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(canvas);
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.lineWidth = 2;
const fish = new Fish(150, 50, 50, 50, 50);
fish.draw();

function Fish(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = 30;

  this.draw = function() {
    const p1 = new Path2D();
    p1.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5, false)
    //Upper Arc
    const p2 = new Path2D();
    p2.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y + (3 * this.radius), this.radius * 4, Math.PI * 229 / 180, Math.PI * 1.5, false)
    //Lower Arc
    const p3 = new Path2D();
    p3.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y - (3 * this.radius), this.radius * 4, Math.PI * 131 / 180, Math.PI * 0.5, true)
    // merge in a single Path2D object

    const path = new Path2D();
    path.addPath(p1);
    path.addPath(p2);
    path.addPath(p3);
    
    c.strokeStyle = "green";
    c.stroke(path);
    
  }
}
```

But in your case you can achieve the expected result quite easily, by changing the order in which you draw your Path and by never calling `moveTo`.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(canvas);
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.lineWidth = 2;
const fish = new Fish(150, 50, 50, 50, 50);
fish.draw();


function Fish(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = 30;

  this.draw = function() {

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5, false)
    // Lower Arc    
    c.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y - (3 * this.radius), this.radius * 4, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 131 / 180, false)
    // Upper Arc
    // (inverse startAngle and endAngle + switch swipe to false)
    c.arc(this.x / 0.6, this.y + (3 * this.radius), this.radius * 4, Math.PI * 229 / 180, Math.PI * 1.5, false)

    c.strokeStyle = "green";
    c.stroke();

  }
}
```

Comment: Finally understand what's going on there ! Thank you so much for your explanation !!  > <